# Android: How to disallow user from changing the permissions on Marshmallow

Tags: android

My app defines several (dangerous) permissions in manifest file and it works great. But (rogue/bad) user can open up settings -> apps -> appname -> permissions to disable the permission and it trips up the app (any time user manually changes the permissions from settings, it invokes App.create() and app reinitializes with disabled permissions)

**How can I prevent user from manually changing the permissions?**

Gradle file looks as follows (I am running the app on 6.0.1, however I donot want to change the target version to 23; hence I am not able to incorporate dangerous permissions from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#perm-groups)

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.XX.main"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 21

}
```

Following figure shows the permissions are enabled and also not greyed out (hence user can disable them)
[image: settings -> apps -> appname -> permissions]

Comment: This is already why it differs from install-time permission. It's not possible prevent user from doing this.

Comment: even with `targetSdkVersion 21` you wont be able to get a user its location on 6.0.

Comment: You can't, but even beyond that-  you shouldn't be allowed to.  This is my phone.  I get to decide what your app can and can't do when running on my hardware.  Not you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I prevent user from manually changing the permissions?

That is not possible. It is the user's device, not yours, and on Android 6.0+, the user can revoke runtime permissions.

> any time user manually changes the permissions from settings, it invokes App.create() and app reinitializes with disabled permissions

Your process will be terminated in many situations. The user disabling runtime permissions is merely one of them. Your app needs to be able to handle its process being terminated, for whatever reason that termination occurs (e.g., free up system RAM while your app is in the background).

> however I donot want to change the target version to 23; hence I am not able to incorporate dangerous permissions

You may still be able to [use `PermissionChecker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/PermissionChecker.html) to see whether the user revoked the permission, so you can do something else and avoid the crash.